# Gradle: Replace Tokens by finding the tokens from property file

Tags: ant, build, gradle

Currently I understand that we can use `org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens` to replace the contents of a file during build in the following way.

`myBeans.xml`:

```
<bean id="mybean1" class="com.test.MyClass1" >
    <property name="myprop1" value="@myproperty@" />
</bean>
```

`my.properties`:

```
myprop=testme
```

gradle file:

```
from file("myBeans.xml"), {
   filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ["myproperty": project.properties["myprop"]])
}
```

However I would want gradle to find the property names from `my.properties` file and replace it in the xml file (without mentioning `myprop` in the filter). If not, I would have to add all the `PlaceHolders` manually.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can pass properties as a map to the ReplaceTokens configuration. The key must match the token you want to see replaced. Example:

beans.xml:

```
<bean id="mybean1" class="com.test.MyClass1" >
    <property name="myprop1" value="@myproperty@" />
</bean>
```

my.properties:

```
myproperty=testme
```

build.gradle:

```
task myCopy(type:Copy){
    from "bean.xml"
    into ("$buildDir/beans")
    def myProps = new Properties()
    file("my.properties").withInputStream{
        myProps.load(it);   
    }
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: myProps)
}
```

hope that helped.

cheers,
René

Comment: `import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens` was the solution for me, thanks!

Comment: Using this, if we need to replace existing build.xml itself , it is emptying the file. Any way to achieve it properly? Using into (to another folder), it is properly copying with replaced content.

Comment: Specifying the parameter name as `tokens` is the key. The actual signature of the `filter` task is `filter(Map<String, ?> properties, Class<? extends FilterReader> filterType)`. Without the named parameter, you will get an exception "Could not set unknown property"