# Output properties file only in jar after gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I have a properties file `VERSIONS.properties` like this in my `src/main/resources`

```
myEnv1.version=3.4.1
myEnv2.version=2.3.2
```

I want that file in remain unchanged in my source unless I want to change the version of my environment. What I expect is after I run `gradle build`, the `VERSION.properties` file inside the output jar will look like this

```
myEnv1.version=3.4.1
myEnv2.version=2.3.2
myApp.version=1.0.1
myModule1.version=0.1.2
myModule2.version=0.1.1
```

Is this even possible and how can I do this. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: If you edit the file and rebuild your jar should contain the updated version. What exactly does not work?

Comment: @cmoetzing  I want it to dynamically change when I edit the version properties in build.gradle

Comment: @Opal What I mean is I want that file in my source just contain the versions of my environment which my project required, but it got appended the project version info at build time into the output jar.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813887/gradle-replace-tokens-by-finding-the-tokens-from-property-file ?

Comment: @cmoetzing Thanks, I think that could work for me.