# Read properties file from build.gradle as well as Java code

Tags: java, gradle

I want to have a properties file that I can set a `version` in and read it in my `build.gradle` file as well as in some Java code.

Every solution I keep seeing/trying is requiring 2 files such as a `gradle.properties` file which I can read from in my `build.gradle` file, and then some other properties file that is in my java classpath that I can read from in my java code.

How can I have a single properties file that can be read from both my `build.gradle` file and my java code?

Comment: You could have your gradle build write the $project.version variable into a resource file which is then packaged in your jar

Comment: Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813887/gradle-replace-tokens-by-finding-the-tokens-from-property-file